# Form Field data in mat-table is not present in Exported document using npm package : mat-table-exporter

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table-exporter

I am using npm package: mat-table-exporter

I am having some form fields in my mat-data-table, which users can fill in runtime, however, on export, the fields are coming as blank.
Below is the stackblitz of the same:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mte-demo-dwz9uo?file=src/app/app.component.html

Also is there a way to ignore any particular row in mat-data-table while exporting?
I have a "No Data present" row in my table which gets conditionally displayed in case there is no data from the backend, but this row comes in exported doc irrespective of data is present or not in the table.